# Update on the Future of Play Framework 1.x

Tags: playframework

I am a *very* happy user of Play Framework. Having developed our app back when 1.2.1 was the current release, we have a Java-based app that currently use the 1.3.x version in production. It has been outstanding.

However, I am still confused about the future of the 1.x version of the Play Framework vs. the 2.x version.

All I seem to read about is the 2.x version; however, I keep seeing "play 1" continue to be updated.

Is there an explanation somewhere of the differences & *current* plans for each version (i.e. Play 1 vs 2)?

(NOTE: I have read the post from a few years back that attempted to clarify the differences. Looking for an update)

Comment: Hi @MSquared, I was a heavy Play1 user and contributor to many modules several years ago. I love play 1's expressive way to get things done and not so happly on where Play 2 is. I've created by own framework to replace play 1, check it out at http://actframework.org

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, consider posting to https://reddit.com/r/scala/.